# WooCommerce Invoice PDFs stop loading halfway in browser

Tags: wordpress, pdf, google-chrome-extension, woocommerce

We've been having an issue in WooCommernce where our .pdf invoices have trouble loading if we try to open them via our browser (both Firefox and Chrome have been tested). The load bar stops halfway and doesn't progress any further. However, this trouble is intermittent. Sometimes it does load, but usually not.

Upon installing the PDF Viewer Extension in Google Chrome, all the pdf invoices loaded for me without issue. However, I can't ask all users to install PDF Viewer Extension and Google Chrome to view pdf invoices. There must be a more all-encompassing solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try opening a console window (network tab) and see what's happening with this request when you click to open the .pdf invoice. See the response headers section and post some extra info and clues about the problem itself.

Comment: As @Igor already mentioned the response headers would be interresting. Take an eye on the "Accept-Ranges" header especially. This could be an issue when the PDFs are generated dynamically.